Matplotlib - How to keep it from putting just a the LSDs of the value on the Y axis?
In Matplotlib I'm creating a scatter plot where all of the data is very close to each other - the numbers vary by a tiny fraction of a percent. Even if I use set_ylim, the Y axis labels are just the least significant digits of the value, with the most significant displayed above the chart (as in the attached picture). Is there a way to make the labels just the entire Y value?
Thanks for your insight

I've tried setting limits with set_ylim. If those limits are far apart it works great; if the limits are close, I get the same result.

Please see the linked duplicate.
